# Problems using remote debugging protocol in Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing my own implementation of DevMode for GWT-like framework. This DevMode is to
work like GWT's old DevMode, which is going to be deprecated, since GWT teavm doesn't want to
support browser plugins. Another reason is NPAPI was removed from latest versions of Google Chrome.
So my DevMode implementation has its own Google Chrome extension, which is written completely in
JavaScript and communicates with server through WebSocket.

The main goal of DevMode is to enable debugging of Java code in Java IDE. It runs Java code
in JVM, and when JVM attempts to execute JavaScript code, it transfers it remotely to browser
extension, which executes JavaScript and sends result back. However, thing are slightly more
difficult in practice, as JVM can pass callback to JavaScript, so there is bi-directional
message flow between JVM and browser extension, in any depth of nesting. Consider the following
ping-pong:

```
public class PingPong {
    public native void ping(int count) /*-{
        console.log("Before ping %d", count);
        this.pong(count - 1);
        console.log("After ping %d", count);
    -}*/;
    public void pong(int count) {
        System.out.println("Before pong " + count);
        ping(count - 1);
        System.out.println("After pong " + count);
    }
}
```

When `ping` calls `pong` it should wait until JVM receives message, handles it and sends response
back. Furthermore, JVM calls `ping` again and so forth. However, WebSocket API is asynchronous.
Also, we can't just block until JVM responds, as JVM may call JavaScript again.

So I use remote debugging protocol in my extension.
When extension receives a command to call a JavaScript method,
it sends the `Runtime.callFunctionOn` command to debugger API. When Java passes callback to
extension, it creates the following proxy function:

```
function() {
    var params = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
        params.push(arguments[i]);
    }
    return sendMessage({
        type : "invoke-method",
        methodName : methodName,
        args : params
    });
}
```

where `sendMessage` is:

```
function sendMessage(message) {
    sentMessage = message;
    while (sentMessage != null) {
        debugger;
    }
    return receivedMessage;
}
```

Further, extension listens to the `Debugger.paused` notification. When a notification comes,
extension sends message to JVM and waits for response. After response is received,
extension sets `receivedMessage`, clears `sentMessage` and sends `Debugger.resume` to debugger.

Unfortunately, I have two major problems. First, I when call

```
element.addEventListener("click", callback)
```

from JVM, and then click the element, `Debugger.paused` comes as expected.
But when I read `sentMessage` through RDP, I get `objectId` different from that I passed to
`addEventListener`. Are objects ids persistent in Google Chrome debugger API?

Second problem is speed. RDP roundtrip takes 10-20 milliseconds on each call. Is there another
way to block execution of script using Google Chrome extension APIs? Also, I want not only
to block, but to enter a nested event loop, since JVM callback may call JavaScript again.

Comment: You speak of an event listener and objectId, but your snippets contain no clues as to what they are.

Comment: Event listener is some function that I pass from JVM to browser extension. To make this function callable from JavaScript, I create a proxy function, as I described. `objectId` is property of type `RemoteObjectId`, which is often present in RDP and describes JavaScript value that is not primitive value. For example, to call a  method through RDP, I pass its name and `objectId` of an object to threat as `this`. Also, when this method returns non-primitive value, it will be in form `{ objectId : "actual id" }`.